# Issue with submission form

Tags: php, html, forms

I have created a PHP form and i want to add Data on my SQL 
Please check my Code where is the Issue whay not working my Code
I want to add all this field on my PHPadmin
but when i enter details and click on Make a payment its not working 
i also add form action="insert.php"
Here is Code

```
<div class="agileits_main_grid_right">
                <div class="wthree_payment_grid">
                    <h2>Seleccione Método de pago</h2>
                    <div id="horizontalTab">
                        <ul class="resp-tabs-list">
                            <li><img src="images/1.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
                            <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt=" " /></li>
                        </ul>
                        <div class="resp-tabs-container">
                            <div class="agileits_w3layouts_tab1">
                                <form action="insert.php" method="post" class="creditly-card-form agileinfo_form">





                                    <section class="creditly-wrapper wthree, w3_agileits_wrapper">
                                        <div class="credit-card-wrapper">
                                            <div class="first-row form-group">
                                                <div class="controls">
                                                    <label class="control-label">Name on Card</label>
                                                    <input class="billing-address-name form-control" type="text" name="name" placeholder="John Smith">
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="w3_agileits_card_number_grids">
                                                    <div class="w3_agileits_card_number_grid_left">
                                                        <div class="controls">
                                                            <label class="control-label">Card Number</label>
                                                            <input class="number credit-card-number form-control" type="text" name="number"
                                                                          inputmode="numeric" autocomplete="cc-number" autocompletetype="cc-number" x-autocompletetype="cc-number"
                                                                          placeholder="&#149;&#149;&#149;&#149; &#149;&#149;&#149;&#149; &#149;&#149;&#149;&#149; &#149;&#149;&#149;&#149;">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="w3_agileits_card_number_grid_right">
                                                        <div class="controls">
                                                            <label class="control-label">CVV</label>
                                                            <input class="security-code form-control"Â·
                                                                          inputmode="numeric"
                                                                          type="text" name="security-code"
                                                                          placeholder="&#149;&#149;&#149;">
                                                        </div>
                                                    </div>
                                                    <div class="clear"> </div>
                                                </div>
                                                <div class="controls">
                                                    <label class="control-label">Expiration Date</label>
                                                    <input class="expiration-month-and-year form-control" type="text" name="expiration-month-and-year" placeholder="MM / YY">
                                                </div>
                                            </div>
                                            <button class="submit"><span>Make a payment <i class="fa fa-long-arrow-right" aria-hidden="true"></i></span></button>
                                        </div>
                                    </section>
                                </form>
                            </div>
```

Comment: And the question is????

Comment: Do you have the code for the processing page `Display.php`? The page you are sending the users to.